# Can Nisei MK II Be Used During an Ice Encounter?

Tags: android-netrunner

This is related to: [How to use 'Nisei MK II' free 'End the run'?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11075/how-to-use-nisei-mk-ii-free-end-the-run)

Say the Corp has a counter on a harvested *Nisei MK II*.

Example 1:
The Runner encounters *Chum* and begins breaking Subroutines on the next piece of Ice. Can the Corp spend the *Nisei MK II* counter before all the Subroutines are broken?

Example 2:
The Runner encounters *Tollbooth* and pays his $3. Can the Corp spend his *Nisei MK II* counter before the Runner has broken the *Tollbooth's* "End Run" Subroutine?

Comment: Welcome! I have a couple of suggestions, since it looks like this is your first question on this site.
#1 You've included a proposed answer as part of your question...I would suggest keeping the question contained, and posting your answer as an answer.
#2 This question is really a strict subset of the related question you linked to, and thus a duplicate. It would probably fit better as a comment asking for clarification on one of the answers there.

Comment: :) submit-on-enter murdered me

Comment: @AndrewVandever I've edited the question to remove "my understanding" clauses. If you still think this can be easily moved to a comment/answered I can do that?

Comment: I'm actually sort of on-the-fence about that, since it is not completely identical, just a more specific question. :) So I'll let others with more calibration make the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but after the runner has a chance to break subroutines, and before any of the unbroken subroutines are resolved.
As pointed out in [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/11078/318), Nisei's is a Paid Ability. From the [rule book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/android-netrunner-core-rules.pdf):

> Cards can also host counters and tokens. Hosted counters or tokens can be spent, or leave play, without affecting their host. If a
> trigger cost requires one or more hosted counters, those counters must
> be spent (returned to the token bank) from the card that the ability
> appears on. (page 22)
>
> Paid Abilities - Some card abilities have trigger costs that a player must pay before the effect of the ability can be resolved.
> These abilities are called paid abilities. A card’s trigger cost is
> always listed in its text box before the effect, following the format
> “cost: effect.” (page 11, sidebar)

As explained in the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf)'s Timing Structure of a Run diagram (last page - phase 3.1) linked from [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/11080/318), a Paid Ability can be triggered during the encounter with the ice - after the runner has a chance to break subroutines, and before unbroken subroutines are resolved. Thus, in the chum example it does not give you any special combo to trigger the net damage, even though you can trigger Nisei before the encounter technically ends. There's a good discussion of this [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/999921/chum-plus-nisei-mk-ii-next-piece-ice).